# Why does a float32 and a float16 np array have a bigger size than a float64 type?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import sys
import numpy as np

a = np.linspace(0, 10, 8, dtype=np.float64)
b = np.linspace(0, 10, 8, dtype=np.float32)
c = np.linspace(0, 10, 8, dtype=np.float16)


print(f'float64 size: {sys.getsizeof(a)} bytes\nfloat32 size: {sys.getsizeof(b)} bytes'
      f'\nfloat16 size: {sys.getsizeof(c)} bytes')
```

which results the following:

> float64 size: 104 bytes

> float32 size: 136 bytes

> float16 size: 120 bytes

Comment: `linspace` has returned a `view` of an unnamed arrray used during its creation.  So `getsizeof` is not a reliable measure of total memory use.  Test `a1=a.copy()` etc